# Setting up a PostgreSQL db for Ruby on Rails locally

Tags: macos, postgresql, rails-postgresql

I'm stumbling on the real basics because I cannot find any clear directions.

I have installed Postgres.app 9.3.5 on OS X.

The documentation tells me how to create a database, `createdb mydb`, but to use it I'd need a PostgreSQL user and a password for that user.

What are the basic steps to create a PostgreSQL *user* with a *password* (and a *database* if different than the above) on a local PostgreSQL install?

Comment: Thanks for including your Pg version. Your operating system would be relevant too though. The mention of `Postgres.app` lets me guess some version of OS X, but ... yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Postgres.app documentation](http://postgresapp.com/documentation/) used to explain this, but appears to have been split up and cut short recently.

You don't need a dedicated user; you can simply use the default `postgres` user. However, because that's a superuser, you're wise to create less privileged users for your apps.

You generally want to make a database *owned by* the app's user, as Rails expects to be able to use the same user to change the schema with migrations as it does to run queries. (It's not great security-wise, but it's the path of least resistance with Rails).

So create the user, then create the db.

Here's how it should look. Don't type the prompts (`$` or `postgres=#`), they're there to show what you're running. Just enter the commands after the prompts.

```
$ psql -q
postgres=# CREATE USER myapp WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'mypassword';
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE myappdb OWNER myapp;
postgres=# \q
```

You may now specify the user, password and database in your `database.yml`.

(Note that Postgres.app may be configured not to require passwords; in this case the password will be ignored by PostgreSQL).

Answer (score 0):

```
createdb mydb
psql -s mydb
create user space_pilot password 'hello';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydb TO space_pilot;
```